# Eloquent Javascript - Chapter 4 on The Arguments Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, arguments

I know there are a ton of EloqJS questions on here, but I haven't seen this one asked and it is throwing me for a loop. I'm curious how the key squirrel in the object entry (squirrel: squirrel) is not replaced by the argument passed by the function in this code:

```
 function addEntry(squirrel) {
  var entry = {events: [], squirrel: squirrel};
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++)
    entry.events.push(arguments[i]);
  journal.push(entry);
}
addEntry(true, "work", "touched tree", "pizza",
         "running", "television");
```

I would expect for it to entry to be {events: [], true: true}, but that is not what this is returning. What am I obviously missing here? Original code at http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html#arguments_object

Comment: You cant pass variables into object keys with the object literal notation, thats why. To do that it should be entry[squirrel] = squirrel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because object keys are literals: they don't change at runtime or act as variables to be replaced with a value.

If you look at the [object initialiser section of the spec (11.1.5)](https://es5.github.io/#x11.1.5), it specifies that an object literal consists of a property name/value list, with property name defined to be one of:

```
IdentifierName
StringLiteral
NumericLiteral
```

The rules for `IdentifierName` [are defined in section 7.6](https://es5.github.io/#x7.6) to include most unicode characters, but not reserved words or whitespace.

Any `IdentifierName` can be wrapped in quotes to become a valid `StringLiteral`, although the inverse is not always true (`StringLiteral`s containing punctuation or whitespace need the quotes to be valid). You can define the object just as well with:

```
{'events': [], 'squirrel': squirrel}
```

As of ES6, there is now a notation to specify that a key should be the value of a variable rather than an identifier or literal of its own. This is [defined in section 12.2.6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer) as a `ComputedPropertyName`, using the `[expr]` syntax. For the object to have a `true: true` property, you could use the ES6 code:

```
{'events': [], [squirrel]: squirrel}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because Object Literal Notation can't receive variables as object keys.

For example:

```
var name = "John";
var person = {
  name: name
}
// person = { name: "John" }

var name = "John";
var person = {};
person[name] = name;
// person = { "John": "John" }
```